# Will a FIFO buffer eventually stagnate?

Tags: data-structures

Below depicts a FIFO buffer:

[image: stagnate]

So the buffer is there for when the speed of data written into the FIFO buffer is faster than the data read.

But I don't understand one thing. Wouldn't eventually all the free buffers of the FIFO buffer run out after certain amount of time? Because writing speed is faster than the read speed.

And if it will stagnate, what is the purpose of using it?

Comment: Maybe the average writing speed is lower that the average reading speed, but the written data comes in bursts.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer is useful if data comes in bursts. 1000 items in a second then 10 seconds nothing and repeat, while the reader reads consistently 100 items per second. Without the buffer, it would take ten seconds to process the 1000 items, then ten seconds nothing - about twice as long.

Yes, if the average write speed is larger than the average read speed then eventually the buffer will fill and you are limited to the average read speed.

Something similar happens if you write at consistent low speed, but the reader reads for one second at high speed and then is not available for ten seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If data is coming continuously then if the writing speed is greater than the reading speed then obviously the buffer will become full.

However, it will not stagnate.

What will happen is that if the buffer is full then writing is stopped but reading will continue and then when some space becomes available in the buffer (because some data has been read from the buffer) then writing will resume.

So, basically, nothing is stagnating but you will lose data.

So, if writing rate is W bytes per second and reading rate is R bytes per second and if W > R, then you will lose W - R bytes per second.